# MYSQL Left Join on multiple table but select only most recent rows

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have three tables (form_completions, customer_sessions and conversion_sessions) which are design like the below, these are heavily striped down for the purpose of this example:

**Form_completions:**

```
id  | name | email
------------------------
101 | Tom  | tom@website.com
102 | Ben  | ben@website.com
```

**Customer_sessions:**

```
id | customer_id | session_id | session_source
---------------------------------
1  | 900         | 9kc73bsf   | twitter
2  | 901         | 15jvuw83   | google
3  | 901         | 45h73bgf   | twitter
```

**Conversion_sessions:**

```
id | customer_id | session_id | form_completion_id
------------------------------------
1  | 900         | 9kc73bsf   | 101
2  | 901         | 45h73bgf   | 102
```

The query that i currently have is:

```
SELECT  custsess.session_source,
        c.id as form_conversion_id,
        c.name,

FROM    conversion_sessions convsess

LEFT JOIN   form_completions fc
ON          convsess.`form_completion_id` = fc.`id`

LEFT JOIN   customer_sessions custsess
ON          custsess.`customer_id` = convsess.`customer_id`
```

This will give me the following:

```
session_source | form_conversion_id | name
------------------------------------------
twitter        | 101                | Tom
google         | 102                | Ben
twitter        | 102                | Ben
```

But what i need is to avoid the duplication of form_conversion_id and only include the most recent so it would be...

```
session_source | form_conversion_id | name
------------------------------------------
twitter        | 101                | Tom
twitter        | 102                | Ben
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: How to know _most recent_?

Comment: Any columns to identify as latest?

Comment: There is a created date within each table, sorry i tried to stripped the tables down to make the example more simple.

Comment: So put that column back into the question's table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your problem:

```
SELECT  custsess.session_source,
        fc.id as form_conversion_id,
        fc.name
FROM    conversion_sessions AS convsess
INNER JOIN   form_completions AS fc
ON convsess.form_completion_id = fc.id
INNER JOIN   customer_sessions AS custsess
ON          custsess.customer_id = convsess.customer_id
AND         custsess.session_id  = convsess.session_id
```

While joining you forgot to join `customer_sessions` and `coversion_sessions` ON `session_id`.

**OUTPUT:**

```
session_source  form_conversion_id  name
twitter                01           Tom
twitter                 102         Ben
```

For demo follow the below link:

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pQG4VCWAnoGtRJa6MkvST6/0

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, i'm also going to include max(session_id) from another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data You should just use inner join

You should use inner join on a subquery for max session_id

```
SELECT  custsess.session_source,
        c.id as form_conversion_id,
        c.name,

FROM    conversion_sessions convsess
customer_sessions custsess ON custsess.`customer_id` = convsess.`customer_id`
INNER JOIN  (
  select customer_id, max(session_id) as  max_sess
  from Customer_sessions
  group by customer_id
) t on t.customer_id = custsess.customer_id and t.max_sess = custsess.session_id

INNER JOIN   form_completions fc ON   convsess.`form_completion_id` = fc.`id`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that gives me the same results with the duplication of rows.

Comment: Thanks you, i'm going to try and add in the max(session_id), for this problem joining on multiple columns (from another answer) seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Subquery to get the most recent, change your JOIN to something like this

```
        LEFT JOIN   customer_sessions custsess
        ON custsess.id =
        (
           SELECT MAX(id) 
           FROM Customer_sessions
           WHERE c.id = custsess.customer_id 
        )
```